# Distance Bachelor's degree in mathematics in Europe

Tags: education

This question is largely off-topic for Mathematics stack exchange, but not entirely. Much of the answer depends on personal experiences in learning mathematics.

I am looking to go back to school for a Mathematics degree (Bachelor). I want to do it for pure knowledge, and not a degree - many areas I'm interested in require a thorough understanding of math. I have very basic calculus/linear algebra (from 1st year Engineering) understanding which is often not enough.

My questions are as follows:

1. Are there severe limitations for doing distance education in mathematics? I have access to people with thorough understanding of higher mathematics who can readily help me if I'm completely stuck.
2. Have you or anyone you know completed distance education degree in mathematics (level of the degree does not matter)? Could you describe some of the experience?
3. Do you know of any universities (especially in Europe, but not necessarily) that offer distance education in mathematics (Bachelor)?

Comment: More than it possibly being off-topic here, it is perfectly on topic on [MESE](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you for asking this interesting question. I also happen to intend to go back to school while working -I'm currently trying to build some foundations by studying by myself and with the help of friends on line here and elsewhere- and know that it isn't as usual, in the case of exact sciences, as with humanities.

Comment: The question got asked on MESE  http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/5557/distance-bachelors-degree-in-mathematics-in-europe

Comment: So is the question closed on Math Stackexchange or not? Where should I give my answer?

Comment: I chose to answer on MESE in the end (short link: http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/5557)